# "Ни одна из ваших учетных записей не может выполнить отправку сообщений этому получателю"

Tags: outlook

```
Сообщение не было получено одним или несколькими получателями.

  Тема: **********************
  Отправлено: 10.07.2018 10:46

Невозможно достичь следующих получателей:

  'mail@domen.ru' 10.07.2018 10:46
        Ни одна из ваших учетных записей не может выполнить отправку 
        сообщений этому получателю.
```

Outlook2010 - ошибка возникает при не верном сохранении кэша. Вместо `SMTP` отправки, сохраняется `MAILTO`

Кэш, это когда при вводе начальных символов адресата появляется облачко с именем и адресом почты (если в этом облачке нажать крестик, кэш этого адресата очистится):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы исправить кэш, необходимо зайти в раздел "Контакты" (выбрать нужную папку контактов) и найти контакт с помощью поисковой строки `Поиск в папке "Контакты"`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего, кликаем два раза по контакту и в поле "Эл. почта..." наводим курсор мыши на адрес почты, в появившемся меню выбираем "Свойства Outlook":

Если не получилось, кликаем по адресу два раза, и в появившемся меню выбираем "Свойства Outlook":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В открывшемся окне выставляем правильные значения, это должно быть `SMTP`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этих действий все должно отправляться. Чтобы проверить получилось ли у Вас, скачайте утилиту NK2Edit ([x32](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nk2edit.zip) | [x64](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nk2edit-x64.zip)) для просмотра кэша в Outlook 2010

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Информация полезная, плюсанул. Но хорошо бы вопрос разделить на вопрос и собственно ответ, и ответить самому на свой же вопрос. Это общепринятая практика здесь на SO, чтобы делиться знаниями. Я бы тогда мог плюсануть не только вопрос, но и ответ :)

Comment: Так же в этом клиенте в настройках имеется кнопка очистки всего кэша адресов. Актуально для пользователей доменных адресных книг